# viewportChecker как удалить класс?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

При помощи плагина viewportChecker  добавляется класс к блоку, когда он оказывается в области экрана

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.block').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated rubberBand',
    offset: 100
  });
});
```

Как удалить класс, когда блок вне экрана? чтобы когда он снова оказывался в поле видимости, срабатывала анимация, как и в первый раз на данный момент.

Answer (score 2):

[Почитайте](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker#options)

Есть опция для этого

```
$('.dummy').viewportChecker({
   ...
   removeClassAfterAnimation: false, // Remove added classes after animation has finished
   ...
});
```

либо используйте аттрибуты

```
<div data-vp-add-class="random"></div>          > classToAdd
<div data-vp-remove-class="random"></div>       > classToRemove
<div data-vp-remove-after-animation="true|false"></div>      > Removes added classes after CSS3 animation has completed
```